# unable to add ionic add platform android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Here is what I can see on my terminal

ionic add platform android

You must have bower installed to continue. 
Type `npm install -g bower` (CLI v1.7.12)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Ionic Version: 1.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.6 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.2.4
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2.1 Build version 7C1002

MacBook-Pro-2:myapp AliSajid$ npm install -g bower
/usr/local/bin/bower -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
bower@1.7.7 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
MacBook-Pro-2:myapp AliSajid$ ionic add platform android

Failed to find the bower component "platform".
Are you sure it exists? (CLI v1.7.12)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Ionic Version: 1.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.6 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.2.4
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2.1 Build version 7C1002

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `ionic add platform android` it should be `ionic platform add android`.

Also if you are safe to reinstall, perhaps try `npm install -g cordova ionic` to ensure all latest dependencies.

Answer (score 13):

The command to add platform have been changed to

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Comment: > cordova.cmd platform add android

    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:659:12) {
  stderr: 'npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL\n' +
    'npm ERR! Could not install from "android" as it does not contain a package.json file.\n' +
    '\n' +
    'npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\n' +
    'npm ERR!     C:\\Users\\Karan\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\_logs\\2019-12-20T10_46_43_877Z-debug.log\n',
  code: 1
}

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to install Bower first with `npm install -g bower`.

Comment: MacBook-Pro-2:myapp AliSajid$ npm install -g bower /usr/local/bin/bower -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower bower@1.7.7 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower MacBook-Pro-2:myapp AliSajid$ ionic add platform android